# react typescript, using prop error: refers to type, but being used as value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use a prop in my React typescript project which is not working.

error:
WidgetProps only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I feel its something very simple I am overlooking.

widget.tsx

```
type WidgetProps = {
mytype: string;
};
const Widget = (props: WidgetProps) => {
  let data;

  switch (WidgetProps.mytype) {
    case "user":
      data = {
        title: "USERS",
        isMoney: false,
        link: "See all users",
        icon: <PersonOutlinedIcon className="icon" />,
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

this is how I'm trying to use it.

home.tsx

```
    <div className="widgets">
      <Widget mytype="user" />
```

Comment: Just change to `props.mytype` in the `switch`. You have your argument and the type mixed up

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface to your `Widget` component

```
export enum WidgetType {
  User = 'user',
  Robot = 'robot'
}


interface WidgetProps {
 type: WidgetType;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
export const Widget = ({ type }: WidgetProps) => {
  let data;

  switch (type) {
    case WidgetType.User:
      data = {
        title: "USERS",
        isMoney: false,
        link: "See all users",
        icon: <PersonOutlinedIcon className="icon" />,
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    
  return (
    <div>Widget</div>
  )
}
```

Then you can call your component like this:

```
 <Widget type={WidgetType.User} />
```

I think this is a much cleaner approach.